# A combinatorial problem about number partition

Tags: combinatorics

Choose eight different numbers from one to twenty, prove that there must exist six different numbers such that $a+b+c=d+e+f$.

Since $\binom{20}{8}$ is only $125970$, I can do it with brute force, but that's not a proof.

Comment: Do the six numbers all have to be distinct?

Comment: @Nishant Yes, question edited.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the six numbers, not the eight numbers, but I assume that's a yes as well?

Comment: @Nishant Yes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A brute force search may not be particularly satisfying as a proof, but it yields the counter-example $$[ 1, 2, 4, 5, 13, 16, 17, 20 ].$$

This can be verified using the [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
counterexample:=[ 1, 2, 4, 5, 13, 16, 17, 20 ];
triples:=Combinations(counterexample,3);
pairs_of_disjoint_triples:=Filtered(Combinations(triples,2),p->Intersection(p[1],p[2])=[]);
0 in List(pairs_of_disjoint_triples,p->Sum(p[1])-Sum(p[2]));
```

which returns `false`.